# Problems with GitHub rendering my README.rst incorrectly..?

Tags: github

I've got a [GitHub repo/branch](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/tree/composer) where I'm attempting to update the README.rst, but it's not formatting the way I expect when it comes to the bullet lists I'm including.

Everything seems ok except for my Usage section, in which I have the following:

```
*****
Usage
*****

- Open the template file that corresponds to the API call you'd like to make.
    * Example: If we want to make a call to the RefundTransaction API we open up /templates/RefundTransaction.php

- You may leave the file here, or save this file to the location on your web server where you'd like this call to be made.
    * I like to save the files to a separate location and keep the ones included with the library as empty templates.
    * Note that you can also copy/paste the template code into your own file(s).

- Each template file includes PHP arrays for every parameter available to that particular API. Simply fill in the array parameters with your own dynamic (or static) data. This data may come from:
    * Session Variables
    * General Variables
    * Database Recordsets
    * Static Values
    * Etc.

- When you run the file you will get a $PayPalResult array that consists of all the response parameters from PayPal, original request parameters sent to PayPal, and raw request/response info for troubleshooting.
    * You may refer to the `PayPal API Reference Guide <https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/>`_ for details about what response parameters you can expect to get back from any successful API request.
        + Example: When working with RefundTransaction, I can see that PayPal will return a REFUNDTRANSACTIONID, FEEREFUNDAMT, etc. As such, I know that those values will be included in $PayPalResult['REFUNDTRANSACTIONID'] and $PayPalResult['FEEREFUNDAMT'] respectively.

- If errors occur they will be available in $PayPalResult['ERRORS']

You may refer to this `overview video <http://www.angelleye.com/overview-of-php-class-library-for-paypal/>`_ of how to use the library, 
and there are also samples provided in the /samples directory as well as blank templates ready to use under /templates.

You may `contact me directly <http://www.angelleye.com/contact-us/>`_ if you need additional help getting started.  I offer 30 min of free training for using this library, 
which is generally plenty to get you up-and-running.
```

For some reason, though, when you look at that on GitHub the first line of the bullet lists is coming up bold and italics and I have no idea why.  Also, the sub-list where it shows Session Variables, General Variables, etc. is supposed to be all the same sub-list.  I'm not sure why it's dropping into another sub when it sees General Variables.

Any information on what I've done wrong here would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch from .rst to .md and then use '`#`' [for your **headings**](https://help.github.com/articles/markdown-basics#headings).

```
## Usage

-  Open the template file that corresponds to the API call you'd like to make.
     * Example
```

Comment: hmmm...that doesn't seem to be working for me at all.  Using the #'s isn't giving me any formatting at all, and the rest is still the same.  Take a look.

Comment: Looks like maybe I need to use .md instead of .rst..??

Comment: Yeah, switching to md seems to be working with this other syntax you linked me to.  Just need to adjust some other things now to get it all working.  Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewAngell I confirm: `.md` file will interpret the markdown correctly.

Comment: @VonC: Of course, but markdown is not restructuredtext. `.rst` files use a different markup language altogether, after all. :-P